# Multiple Where Statements

Tags: magento2, database, module, magento-1, sql

I have the following line of code

```
$select =  $read->select()
            ->from($batchTable,array('id','batch','strength','flavor','brand'))
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->order('created DESC') ;
```

How do I do multiple where statements?

Comment: Given Magento is built around Zend - you can reference the Zend manual for a lot of functionality. The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.where) is very exhaustive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$select =  $read->select()
            ->from($batchTable,array('id','batch','strength','flavor','brand'))
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('other_field', 'some_value')
            ->where('an_other_one' <> ?', 8)
            ->order('created DESC');
```